# Markov chain problem, Help!

Tags: stochastic-processes, matlab, markov-chains

I am stuck on this question for a long time
Question:

Consider 4 balls, labelled from 1 to 4 and distributed amongst two urns
(Urn 1 and Urn 2). At each time $n>1$, a number from 1 to 4 is chosen at
random. The ball with that label is then transferred from one urn to the
other. Each ball is equally likely to be chosen at any time. Let $Xn$ denote
the number of balls in Urn 1 at time n.

(i) Draw the steady state diagram and construct the transition matrix for
the process $Xn$.

i have drawn the steady state diagram and get the transition matrix
\begin{bmatrix}0&1&0&0&0\\1/4&0&3/4&0&0\\0&1/2&0&1/2&0\\0&0&3/4&0&1/4\\0&0&0&1&0\end{bmatrix}

(ii). Using MATLAB, or otherwise, investigate the long-run behaviour of
the probability state vector $P^{n}$ at time n. [Display outputs of $P^{n}$; 
perhaps via a plot of each component versus time n.] Does your answer
depend on the initial state? Find the eigenvalues of T (a numerical
estimate will suffice)

I dont know how to start part 2, i know $P^{n}$ = $P^{0}T^{n}$

How can i find $p^{0}$?

Comment: $P^n=P^{n-1}Q$ where $Q$ is the transition matrix you have

Comment: that's right but how do i find $p^{n-1}$ ?

Comment: using matlab or otherwise

Comment: Insert your last formula and calculate the powers of the matrix in Matlab. Then in each step you can plot the probability of every state transition in a graph.

Comment: Calculate them recursively. Starting from P0

Comment: but what is $p^{0}$?

Comment: You are supposed to choose p0. The question asks you to "how does  your answer depend on the initial state." That means, choose a couple different values of p0 and see what happens.

Comment: I am wondering the sum of those values in $p^{0}$ must be equal to 1? Eg: \begin{bmatrix}0.2&0.8&0&0&0\end{bmatrix}

Comment: Yes water723, Po is the initial state and the sum of its entries must equal 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should find that, for every initial distribution $P^0$, the distribution $P^n$ at time $n$ is some linear combination $P^n=pR_n+(1-p)S_n$ where:

- $p=P^0(0)+P^0(2)+P^0(4)$
- $R_n$ and $S_n$ are probability distributions
- $R_{2n}$ and $S_{2n+1}$ have support $\{0,2,4\}$
- $S_{2n}$ and $R_{2n+1}$ have support $\{1,3\}$
- $R_{2n}$ and $S_{2n+1}$ converge to $\frac18\cdot(1,0,6,0,1)^T$
- $S_{2n}$ and $R_{2n+1}$ converge to $\frac12\cdot(0,1,0,1,0)^T$

Thus, $P^n$ converges if and only if $p=\frac12$, in which case
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}P^n=\tfrac1{16}\cdot(1,4,6,4,1)^T.
$$

Comment: sorry i am a bit confused. why is Pn converges if and only if p=1/2? @Did

Comment: Because otherwise, there are two distinct limit points, one for $(P^{2n})$ and the other for $(P^{2n+1})$..